# tableView.reloadData() does not work in Xcode 7 beta 4 and Swift2 using Simulator

Tags: swift2

Calling tableView.reloadData() prompts a call to numberOfRowsInSection but never a call to cellForRowAtIndexPath. I can't try this on my device because I need iOS 8.4 for the production version of my app.

Anyone else encounter this or have a solution?

Comment: I have the same behavior on my iPad which has iOS 9. The weird thing is that if I just tap the screen, all data appears as if it just executed reloadData().

Comment: You are probably calling `reloadData()` from a background queue. Use `dispatch_async` to switch to the main queue, then call it.

Comment: I was and dispatch_async on the main queue worked. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably calling `reloadData()` from a background queue. Use `dispatch_async` to switch to the main queue, then call it.

Answer (score 0):

When calling tableView.reloadData() or any other function or method that controls the user interface from an async block or background queue, you must call it using dispatch_async using the main queue, e.g.:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
    self.tableView.reloadData()
})
```

Answer (score -1):

This would occur if your `numberOfRowsInSection` returns zero.

As for the device part of your question, you could consider updating your device to the official 8.4 iOS like 90% of iOS users already have.

Comment: numberOfRowsInSection returns 3 and my iPhone has 8.4, the trouble is I am using Xcode 7 targeting iOS 9. My iPad has the current beta of iOS 9 but exhibits the same behavior.